# WPF DataGrid ComboBox retrieving value before commit

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, combobox, commit

I've got a DataGrid in a WPF application (with Entity Framework) that has a `ComboBox` as one of the columns in it. This `ComboBox` is bound to a datasource that is using a joined reference to a table that contains the names being displayed in the dropdown.  It's using an ID field (called SalesActMgrID) for this join. I'm populating the dropdown list with just a List<> of specific names from that table.

My problem is that when a Name is selected from the dropdown list, it's changing the name in that joined table instead of changing the **SalesActMgrID** to the selected name.

I've figured out a way to update the ID in my datasource, but I haven't figured out a way to find out what name was selected in the dropdown so that I can get the correct ID for that name.

The combo column is defined as:

```
               <DataGridComboBoxColumn 
                    SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Path=ClientContract.StaffRole_SalesActMgr.StaffName}" 
                    Header="Sales Act Mgr" 
                    x:Name="salesActMgrColumn" Width="Auto" >
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" 
                                Value="{Binding staffNamesListSAM}" />
                        <Setter Property="IsReadOnly"
                                Value="True" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

The DataGrid is bound to a Datasource of EmployeeTime.
The complete join of the tables are:

```
EmployeeTime.ClientContractID is joined to ClientContract.ClientContractID {M-1}
StaffRoles.StaffRoleID is joined to ClientContract.SalesActMgrID {1-M}
```

I'm using the following code to perform commits on a cell by cell edit.

```
    private bool isManualEditCommit;

    private void consultantsDataGrid_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!isManualEditCommit)
        {
            isManualEditCommit = true;
            string head = e.Column.Header.ToString();
            bool doCommit = true;

            switch (head)
            {
                case "Sales Act Mgr":
                    {
                        e.Cancel = true;
                        //This is where I have been able to 'hard code' in a different
                        //ID value into the SalesActMgrID field which then correctly
                        //updates the value, but I need to know what name was selected
                        //here so I can get the correct ID for that name and set it below.
                        ((EmployeeTime)e.EditingElement.DataContext).ClientContract.SalesActMgrID = 11;
                        doCommit = false;
                    }
                    break;
            }
            DataGrid grid = (DataGrid)sender;
            if (doCommit)
            {
                grid.CommitEdit(DataGridEditingUnit.Row, doCommit);
                EmployeeTime et = e.Row.Item as EmployeeTime;
                CreateBurdenValue(et);
            }
            else
            {
                grid.CancelEdit(DataGridEditingUnit.Row);
            }
            isManualEditCommit = false;
        }
    }
}
```

There may be some other 'better' way to do this, which I would love to find out. At the least, if someone can point me in a direction in which I can get the selected name that was just selected before any commit action is done, I would appreciate that.

Just for info, if I let it go through and do a normal CommitEdit on the cell, the selected name is actually getting updated in the StaffRole table so on every row in the grid that displayed the original name, they get changed to the new selected name (which is not what I'm wanting).

Comment: Sure enough, I've been searching for an answer for this for the past several days.  After I post this, the very next time I continue with my searching I finally find the answer:  (e.EditingElement as ComboBox).SelectionBoxItem

Answer (score 0):

I will just summarize what the OP posted in the comment. To access the selected item in the edit handler, use:

```
 (e.EditingElement as ComboBox).SelectionBoxItem
```